# Assigning two classes to the same variable, is that even possible?

Tags: swift, swift5

I have two classes belonging to the same protocol.

```
class CameraModel:CaptureProtocol {
}

class ScannerModel:CaptureProtocol {
}
```

at one point on the app I want to load one or the other on a variable

```
var model = preferences.digitizer == .camera ? cameraModel : scannerModel
```

is there a way to do that, even using `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define protocol data type

```
var model: CaptureProtocol = preferences.digitizer == .camera ? cameraModel : scannerModel
```

or use computed property

```
var model: CaptureProtocol { preferences.digitizer == .camera ? cameraModel : scannerModel }
```

Note: You can access only protocol properties from the model var.

Comment: I did that and I have this error: Protocol 'CaptureProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Comment: Use computed property ```var model: CaptureProtocol { preferences.digitizer == .camera ? cameraModel : scannerModel }```

Comment: @Duck update your question with the definition of `CaptureProtocol`